# How to color cells of Voronoi diagram

Tags: c++, boost

I have created a vector of points. Each point can have any of the specified 16 colors. I am able to create a Voronoi diagram using the Boost library but am unable to color the cells efficiently. The Boost documentation says that there is a function as below :

```
void color(color_type color) const
```

to set color of the cells but I am unable to find any implementation example of it. The way Voronoi diagram is created, I um unable to do it. Please point in the right direction. This is what I have till now.

```
struct Point {
    double a;
    double b;
    Point(double x, double y) : a(x), b(y) {}
};

// This point is mapped to Point concept of Boost.Code omitted

std::vector<Point_Collection> *points_info_vector;
points_info_vector = new std::vector<Point_Collection>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    Point_Collection xy_color = { Point(rand() % 1000, rand() % 1000), rand() % 16 };
    points_info_vector->push_back(xy_color);
}


std::vector<Point> *points;
points = new std::vector<Point>();

for (int i = 0; i < points_info_vector->size(); i++) {
    points->push_back(points_info_vector->at(i).xy);

}


voronoi_diagram<double> vd;

construct_voronoi(points->begin(), points->end(), &vd);
```

Also, is there a more efficient way of using the construct_voronoi() with our Point_Collection structure without making a temporary structure just for points?

Comment: Why do you use new to allocate a vector<>*?  This breaks all RAII rules.

Comment: What are the other efficient ways to do it? Please point in the right direction.

Comment: A vector<> object is 4 pointers long,  It will handle all memory allocation for you.  You can declare it as a local variable.

Comment: Can you please explain it with an example or link some resource for it? I didn't get you.

Answer (score 1):

Found a partial answer : We can iterate over the cells and find out the index of the input geometry that is given by the builder library. Quoting the documentation :

> Source index corresponds to the unique id, issued to each input geometry (e.g. incremental counter, used by the Voronoi builder).

So, I can do :

```
for (voronoi_diagram<double>::const_cell_iterator it = vd.cells().begin(); it!= vd.cells().end(); it++ )
{       
    std::cout << it->source_index() << "\n" ;
    it->color(points_info_vector->at(it->source_index()).color);
}
```

So, from this index I can use the `void color(color_type color) const` to set the color of the cell from my earlier vector index.

Still, I would like to know an efficient way to create Voronoi diagram with the custom structure iterator as the function parameter, without having to copy the points to other vector.